# Numeric abbreviations in business quotes

Tags: writing, numbers

When writing a quote for an order for products, would you write

25K or 25M to refer to 25,000 parts or pounds or units?

Comment: 25K for 25,000, 25M for 25,000,000.

Comment: If you're writing a quote, make it explicit and write 25000.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_prefix

Comment: @RegDwighт English numeric abbreviations aren't quite the same as binary prefixes: For example, they generally use uppercase _K_ for thousands and _B_ for billions instead of _giga._

Comment: @Bradd point taken, but that information, too, is to be found on Wikipedia, in fact by following links from that article. Not to mention that in either system the two letters in question mean the same thing, so this is really a non-starter. My comment is only there because when closing a question as general reference, it is considered good practice to provide a link to the "internet reference source designed specifically to find that type of information". In this case that's Wikipedia. Strictly speaking it would be sufficient to link to its home page, or the article on the letter M.

Comment: As Patrick M notes in his answer to my question, M and K actually are ambiguous in some contexts and require more than a general reference to explain.

Comment: Suggested an edit to invite a canonical answer. If it makes it through the queue, I'll flag for moderator attention to reopen. (If it doesn't, I'll re-ask, because I think it deserves attention.) Also, I have not found anything in the help center to indicate that technical/jargon/niche questions are off-topic.

Comment: Aaand [rejected](http://english.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/82576). And [reasked](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/193246)!

Answer (score 8):

In English numeric abbreviations and currency:

- K for *thousand* (from *kilo*)
- M for *million*
- B for *billion*
- T for *trillion*

In [metric prefixes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SI_prefix) for SI measurements:

- k for *thousand* (note lowercase)
- M for *million* (from *mega*)
- G for *billion* (from *giga*)
- T for *trillion* (from *tera*)

Therefore, 25K is 25,000 units. You could also write 25k (lowercase *k*). These abbreviations are appropriate for summary text but not itemized lists or tables. In that case, should not abbreviate (although you may specify *all numbers in thousands* in the legend if appropriate).

Comment: This answer and all discussion on this question miss the point that the asker was specifically mentioning "business quotes." In accounting, [**M** usually means thousands and **MM** means millions (and K is not used)](http://www.accountingcoach.com/blog/what-does-m-and-mm-stand-for). This is a dumb practice, in my opinion; I would vote to reopen the question as I think it would benefit from a lengthy, canonical answer for when to use **M** = thousand and how to recognize the authors intent when reading, especially when **MM** and **K** are not present.

Comment: (The world stopped using Roman Numerals, and not because we ran out of them.)

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out! I'd never heard of it. Since it appears to be technical jargon rooted in Latin, it might still be off topic, but it's good to have the information. Maybe I'll edit my answer if I have time.